# Laravel Model is not getting data

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a model called `MongodbServer` and the database table name is `mongodb_servers`. Now when I want to get all the data using :

```
$MongodbServers = MongodbServer::get();

var_dump( $MongodbServers );
```

I am getting this error:

> object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#1065 (2) {
> ["items":protected]=> array(0) { }
> ["escapeWhenCastingToString":protected]=> bool(false) }

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the table actually have data?

Comment: @RobertRocha Kill me please :( :( :(

Comment: No worries. Additionally if you want to get all the data you would do something like ```MongodbServer::all();```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error what you are posting. `var_dump` is describing the `$MongodbServers` variable. [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.var-dump.php) you can find more about it.

So as you can see in the dump your object is a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. Now you could iterate through your items for example. For this you could use the following code snipet:

```
$MongodbServers->each(function ($item) {
    // Some code
});
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html) are more informations about the possibilities with an eloquent collection.

Edit: I just saw the `"items":protected]=> array(0)` in the dump what means that you don't have any entries in your db.